# Node JS Rendering Blank Page

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a problem where if I connect to localhost:3000 or 127.0.0.1:3000, I get a completely blank page.

Here is the code via GitHub
https://github.com/InfamousGamez/halp

Here is a picture localhost:3000, what I currently am running node on.
http://gyazo.com/1b92c35798bef88980eaec882572d851

Is there something wrong with my code or is it a express/node error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing `<%-body%>` in your `layout.ejs`. So the `index.ejs` is being rendered, but since you don't include the `body` in your layout, nothing is shown.